Can't get Cursor to work with Django linting
I have Python code in a Django project that says:
x = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=2, default='0.00')

In Cursor, I get a Linter error from pylance:
"No overloads for "__new__" match the provided argumentsPylancereportCallIssue"


I have
    "python.analysis.django": true,

in my settings.json, but it is greyed out.
The code runs fine interactively, and when I run pylance from the terminal it doesn't flag this error.
I have the django-stubs package installed in my venv.
It seems like pylance in Cursor doesn't know about Django, and I can't figure out why. Any suggestions most appreciated!
